# How to register button click

Tags: php, html

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-icon-text" id = "LOAD">
    <i class="mdi mdi-upload btn-icon-prepend"></i>LOAD
</button>
```

php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['LOAD']))
    {
        exit();
    }
?>
```

when i click the button, nothing happens. sorry i am really new to html and php. i have tried multiple other methods but none work :(

Comment: Can you describe more of your question?

Comment: when i click the button, nothing happens thats the issue

Comment: a button, of type `button` will do nothing by default. You need to use Javascript to make it do something interesting

Comment: yea i want it to just exit when its pressed

Comment: Does the HTML form part of a FORM? If so please add the remainder of the form. Also the PHP lacks the opening `session_start()` and is likely just a portion. Please add sufficient code to reproduce the error/fault and try to clearly define the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-icon-text" id = "LOAD">
<i class="mdi mdi-upload btn-icon-prepend"></i>LOAD
</button>
```

That's just a HTML code, so it will not trigger anything. You need little bit javascript.

Also remember, php loads before javascript. So you can't trigger php with javascript if you don't use AJAX or redirect etc.

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("LOAD").onclick = function(){
       window.location.href = window.location.href+"?LOAD=1"; 
  }
</script>
```

If you add that javascript code, button will refresh the page and redirect the same page with GET parameter.
You can control the GET parameter on the PHP side.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['LOAD']))
{
    exit();
}
?>
```

It's not efficient path but if you understand the mechanics, you can figure it out.

Research AJAX.

Comment: ye i want to update database once the button is clicked

Comment: Then AJAX will help you. Create an update.php and send parameters to it with javascript. Then update.php will return to javascript with some data(your choice) and you can parse that data and manipulate your html, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the button name (which is different from the id)

try `name="LOAD"` as in:

```
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-icon-text" id="LOAD" name="LOAD">
           <i class="mdi mdi-upload btn-icon-prepend"></i>LOAD
      </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Fire FN maybe just use JS then